# Where can I get PortableDevice.h or WPD defined constant GUIDs and such?

Tags: c#, constants, wpd

I'm digging into a project, dealing with [Windows Portable Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/windows-portable-devices) (WPD).  Everything I am going through has *WPD_[some name]*, *WPD_[some other thing]*, etc.  All the documentation pages I find refer to these constants.  But under the hood, these constants are directly associated to some constant GUID values.

How / where do these constants exists?   Some documentation says to look into PortableDevices.h, and everything I look for on that just points to more named constants, not the corresponding GUIDs.

For example,

```
WPD_CATEGORY_CAPABILITIES = Guid("0cabec78-6b74-41c6-9216-2639d1fce356")
```

Another page to show a good example of all these "WPD_" references can be found [on Microsoft's pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/portable/the-wpdbasichardwaredriver-supporting-wpd-capability-commands).

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but... [maybe?](https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=title%3AWPD_*+AND+valuetype%3ASystem.Guid)

Comment: @DavidG, yup... that is close enough.  Post as an answer so I can check it off.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look around, I found the Magic Number Database which lists all of these values. The link, with a filter applied to only show those you need, is

https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=title%3AWPD_%2A+AND+valuetype%3ASystem.Guid

However, that site also gives the path of the file in which those values are sourced from which points at the Windows Driver Kit so my advice would be to grab that, install it and find the header file in this folder (you may need to tweak the version number if the WDK has been updated):

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\PortableDevice.h
```

Download the WDK from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk).